# Could my cat catch something from this oddly-acting mouse?

Tags: cats, safety, diseases, mice, hunting

So this all started at one A.M., when I usually go down to get a cat to lay with me in bed. When I opened the door to let them in, I noticed that our oldest kitty had something in his mouth, so I went to investigate.

It was a mouse. A living, squeaking mouse.

The second the cat saw me look at the thing, he dropped it, and I managed to get a basket over it before my other cats could kill the poor thing. I put him outside and, after a moment, he started to move! I was really happy, but I noticed some odd behaviour, and I want to make sure that my kitty isn't in any danger.

At first, he fidgeted a bit, clearly coming out of shock, and then began to wash the saliva off of himself. As he got up to move, I noticed that he was moving in lazy circles. Not constantly, only three or four times, and he'd stop to groom himself or have a sniff at something, so I'm wondering if he was cleaning his tail? Then again, I've also seen that rabies or toxoplasmosis symptoms could cause circling. Or perhaps the shock of it all?

As I'm writing this, it's about ten minutes since I saw him circling, and he's no longer in sight of my window. What do you guys think? Should I be worried?

EDIT: My apologies, it appears my question wasn't clear. The question here is: Should I be worried about my cat catching something from the mouse?

Comment: first of all this is about a mouse living outside so it is not a pet,this makes it off topic here.and it is not clear what you are asking the problem is not clear to me.and it is no reason to be woried about things you have no controll over.

Comment: @trondhansen I'm sorry if it wasn't clear, but I was asking if my cat may be in danger of catching something from the mouse like plasmodium. I was in a bit of a panic when I typed my original question.

Comment: If you don't live in [rabies free country](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17778/is-germany-or-any-of-europe-really-rabies-free) does your cat have a rabies vacination?

Comment: @JamesJenkins cats in a rabies free country does not get rabies vaccsine(like where i live in norway)but the vet will give the rabies vaccsine if one plan to take the pet out of the country(it is not legal to bring un vaccsinated pets into other countries).

Comment: @trondhansen that is what my comment implies "If you don't live in rabies free country" = if you live in country that might have rabies. We don't know what country the OP lives in. But both your answer and the one from Elmy address it as well.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like perfectly normal behavior.

Imagine you were almost swallowed by a giant beast and then suddenly put into an unknown place. Wouldn't you turn around and try to orient yourself?

The mouse was probably

1. Trying to assess whether the cat was still around
2. Trying to orient itself
3. Trying to find a way back home or at least back to known territory

As to the health of your cats, you should make sure they get at least the default vaccines for outside cats which usually have to be refreshed each year. If your area is known for rabies in wild animals, make sure to vaccinate your pets and yourself as well. Otherwise I wouldn't worry too much.

Answer (score 6):

I do not think you need to be worried about your cat getting infected with *Toxoplasma gondii*; a very large number of cats do have this and it is not dangerous for a healthy cat.

The main danger from [toxoplasmosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxoplasmosis) is to pregnant women or animals, but only if they are infected during pregnancy (there is a risk of miscarriage). If the woman or animal is infected some time before pregnancy, the woman or animal will be immune and is no longer in danger of losing the baby.

When it comes to [rabies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabies), the risk for your cat is small unless the cat has a wound where the illness can enter the cat's body. So if your cat have been bitten by the mouse, it might be infected.

The cat will not be infected by eating an infected mouse unless the cat has a wound, but this being said, you need to **keep the rabies vaccine up to date** for your cat. This is done every two years, I believe.

More information about rabies in cats could be found [in this article on petmd.com](https://www.petmd.com/cat/conditions/neurological/c_ct_rabies).

[Here is some information about the vaccines a cat needs](https://pets.webmd.com/cats/cat-vaccines#1).

Finally, if you live in an area where rabies is found, your cat should get this vaccine as a part of the vaccination program your vet has for your cat. Be sure to contact your new vet if you move house, so you can keep all of the vaccines up to date.